# WMS request causes Geoserver Lat/Lon Bounding Box to Change

Tags: geoserver, wms, extents

I have a layer with the following bounding box:

[image: bounding box before request]

A bot (baidu spider) has been making the following request periodically:
/geoserver/si-x/wms/kml?layers=si-x:zabelli_leaf_ncep

This request causes the bounding box to change to the following:

[image: bounding box after request]

Any ideas why? If I click "Compute from native bounds" and save the layer it will be fine until the bot hits the layer again at which point the bounds revert to the numbers in the second screen shot. If I make a similar request from a browser

`http://myGeoserver/geoserver/wms/kml?&layers=gdd:agdd_50f`

I don't receive an error, a .kml file downloads, and the bounds of the layer are messed up again. Any ideas on why this request would cause the Lat/Lon Bounding Box of the layer to change?

Comment: Sounds really odd and it would be interesting to reproduce the issue. What datastore do you use?

Comment: The datastore is ImageMosaic using the Image mosaicking plugin.

Comment: I'd be really interested to know if anyone is successful or not in replicating this behavior. In my particular case the layers are time-series raster layers using imagemosaic. Imagemosaic looks to postgres to get the paths of daily geotifs which it then serves out. At this point I'm trying to figure out if it's a bug or a configuration issue.